# Configuring GCM cipher suites in Jetty based server

Tags: tls, java, cipher-selection

I have a Jetty based secure http service, and I wish to support GCM cipher suites. I know that Jetty internally use JSSE based ciphers, and there are many GCM ciphers coming with JSSE as documented here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#ciphersuites

However, I can't get Jetty to support any of these. For eg: I configure the below ones for Jetty

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

but are not listed as supported ciphers from an SSL scan.

I searched a lot, and also cannot figure out where to look for available JSSE ciphers in a distribution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document you are linking to lists only the standard cipher suite *names*; it does not promise that all these cipher suites are actually supported by any JSSE provider, in particular the one which comes with Java and is called `SunJSSE`. That the standard name `TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` is defined just means that **if** a JSSE provider wants to provide support for that cipher suite, **then** it must provide it *under that name*.

[This document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider), which allegedly pertains to Java 7 as well, lists the cipher suites which `SunJSSE` actually supports; some enabled by default, others disabled by default. I see no GCM cipher suite at all...

Support for GCM cipher suites may be added in a future version; you might want to try [some previews of Java 8](http://jdk8.java.net/) (Java 8 release is due March 2014). In any case, GCM cipher suites in SSL require TLS 1.2 (they don't work with previous protocol versions), and the `AES_256` is 256-bit AES which, with the cryptographic implementations provided with Java, requires the [JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html) (a remnant of the US export regulations on cryptographic material).

Comment: Thanks! TLS 1.2 is already supported in my case, and have patched the jdk distribution with JCE unlimited policy files. I tried with JDK8 as well, but it doesn't provide GCM cipher suites. Perhaps I should experiment with some JCE providers. I had a quick test with Bouncy Castle library, but looks like it doesn't offer any GCM suites either. :(